JavaScript button to change image source not working
I have a set of buttons that each need to change an image to a different source, and show which one is selected (retain onclick appearance).
I want it to take the name of an element from a list and do things based on variables for that item, but mainly set the source and title.
script:
    const picList= {
      { "nature": { src: "nature.png", title: "" } }
      { "face":   { src: "face.png", title: "" } }
    };

    function changePic(picName) 
    {
      document.getElementById('currentPic').src = picList[picName].src;
      document.getElementById('currentPic').title = picList[picName].title;
    }

body:
<img id="currentPic" src="nature.png">
          <button onclick="changePic('face')" type="button">Face</button> 
          <button onclick="changePic('nature')" type="button">Nature</button> 

A lot of suggestions have me creating a const to hold the list item data, but that isn't working and it should be the same to set each element right?
Now I only see the image it starts with, nature.png and onclick doesnt seem to do anything. I'm seeing some posts say it needs to return false but that isn't working either.
Also, if I want the button to retain the onclick darker color until another button is clicked, where would be a good place to reset it when another button is clicked?

You should check your browser console for errors, that'll give you the first hint as to what's wrong. Currently, your object is invalid picList, you should remove the surrounding { and } for nature and face and use commas to separate each key-value pair.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Your Object contains too many curly braces and a comma is missing, change it to const picList= { "nature": { src: "nature.png", title: "" }, "face": { src: "face.png", title: "" } };

THANK YOU neocities doesnt seem like it has any console so I'm debugging in the dark!

@AlexMurray Consoles have nothing to do with the provider your site runs on. It's your browser that has a debugger with a console. Press F12 to open the debugger, then click the the tab labeled "Console".

It is generally not a good idea to use inline event handlers.
Here's an idea for you to work with. The snippet uses event delegation for the click handling and
data-attributes to identify the image id and image src.


document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

// note: your object literal contained errors
// (no comma between properties, too many/ 
//  unnecessary curly braces)
const picList = {
  nature: {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/id/29/200/100",
    title: "it's nature"
  },
  face: {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/id/64/200/100",
    title: "an image of a face"
  },
  original: {
    src: "https://picsum.photos/id/16/200/100",
    title: "the original picture"
  }
};

function handle(evt) {
  const imgChangeFromButton = evt.target.dataset.imgChange;

  if (imgChangeFromButton) {
    const img = document.querySelector(evt.target.dataset.imgId);
    img.setAttribute(`src`, picList[imgChangeFromButton].src);
    img.setAttribute(`title`, picList[imgChangeFromButton].title);
    document.querySelector(`.selected`).classList.remove(`selected`);
    return evt.target.classList.add(`selected`);
  }
}
button[data-img-change] {
  color: #c0c0c0;
}

button[data-img-change]:hover {
  color: green;
}

button[data-img-change].selected {
  color: red;
}
<img id="currentPic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/16/200/100">
<p>
  <!-- note: you don't need type="button" -->
  <button 
    data-img-change="face" data-img-id="#currentPic">Face</button>
  <button 
    data-img-change="nature" data-img-id="#currentPic">Nature</button>
  <button 
    data-img-change="original" data-img-id="#currentPic" class="selected">Original</button>  
</p>



